# which operation is exactly blocking the main thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, internet-connection

when you make a network connection in Android you are blocking the main thread , so you have to move "some" of this task to a new thread

I have 2 questions on this part

1- which of the following operation is blocking the main thread (A or B)

```
//A:
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection(); 

//B:
InputStream stream=c.getInputStream();
```

2- if "both" of the above (A & B) must run in a new thread , dose it have a bad effect to run each one in a new separate thread? take a look to the following code:

```
//I temporary removed try & catch to simplify the code 
public class connect{
HttpURLConnection c; String url;
 public connect(String url){
   this.url=url;
   new Thread(new Runnable{
   @override public void run(){
    c = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
  }
});

}
 public InputStream get(){
  return c.getInputStream();
 //or make this one in a new thread

  }

public InputStream post(Sring params){
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
//.. make some code for posting data , and then call get()
//thats why i cannot perform c.getInputStram() at the same time with openConnection()
return get()


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> which of the following operation is blocking the main thread (A or B)?

It is pretty evident that both operations A and B will block the main thread. Just calling the following on the main thread will throw an exception(*NetworkOnMainThreadException*) right away:

```
 HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
```

Also when you are calling the following line on main thread:

```
InputStream stream=c.getInputStream();
```

You are simply trying to read a stream of bytes over a network. Now there are various factors that will determine the time taken by this operation to complete. For instance, network speed, overall number of bytes that you want to read, etc. The application should not really need to wait and stay idle till the reading process has been completed. All the UI related process should be able to run and consume the resources as a user reacts with your application which will not be possible because of the ongoing byte reading process which is actually blocking the main thread.

> if both A and B must run in a new thread , dose it have
>   a bad effect to run each one in a new separate thread?

Technically, yes it is bad to run both in separate threads. Besides why would you want to do so? Before initiating stream reading process you need to make sure that the connection has been opened. Calling A and B in separate threads will raise concurrency issues. You must call B after A so if you even resolve concurrency issues, it will be of no use to make two separate threads.

**EDIT:**

So as you said in comments that you want to avoid using `AsyncTask`. An alternative for that is **Java Threads**. Check out the following sample usage of threads:

```
static public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

                // add your url and open connecttion here
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("your url here")).openConnection();
                // read stream or whatever data you want
                InputStream stream = c.getInputStream();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //close your connection & wipe input stream here.
            }
        }
    }
```

Now here is how we can call this thread:

```
private Thread downloadThread = new MyThread();
downloadThread.start();
```

At any time, you can also check if your thread is running or not by using the following code:

```
if (downloadThread != null && downloadThread.isAlive()) {
    // do something when thread is alive here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses handler to connect main thread with background thread(the thread that does the HTTP connection stuff)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Thread mThread;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startThread();
  }


  public void startThread(){
      String url = "www.google.com";
       String result = "";
    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            InputStream is = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            try {
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
                if (connMgr != null) {
                    networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                }
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() && !mThread.isInterrupted()) {
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    is = conn.getInputStream(); 

                     //Here you get the result from inputStream


                }
                threadMsg(result);

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void threadMsg(String msg) {

            if (msg != null && !msg.equals("") && !mThread.isInterrupted()) {
                Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("message", msg);
                msgObj.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
            }
        }
        private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String result = msg.getData().getString("message");
                // What you want to do in UI thread
            }
        };

    });
    mThread.start();
  }
```

Comment: i want to avoid AsyncTask

Comment: Ok, tomorrow i will send a sample code working with handlers and looper.